# how to use System.Data.Services.Client in C#?

Tags: c#, bing, bing-api

I was trying to use the `Bing Search API` in my C# program. When I try

`using System.Data.Services.Client;` in my program, it gives me the following error:

`The type or namespace name 'Services' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data' (are you missing an assembly reference?)`

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 in Windows 7 64bit version. & I am new to programing and not sure how to set assembly references. Can I please tell me how can I solve this?

Comment: I don't know, *are you* perhaps *missing an assembly reference?*

Comment: Google that class, find its page on MSDN, see what DLL it says it is in, add a reference to that DLL to your project. Report back if that doesn't fix your problem.

Comment: I am really glad to find this question, being new to this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add Reference

[image: Add Reference]

System.Data.Services.Client

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining it to me with such details. It helped a lot. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @Caleb I have tried to add those .dll from references like you mentioned but still it gives me the same error?

Comment: @Rana Try cleaning and rebuilding your project. Also, be sure you are using the latest version of the DLLs.